# Changing form 'method' doesn't work, browser makes 'GET' request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to create a simple CRUD app, to a FLASK backend via JSON. The JSON queries work fine.
The HTML form I am using doubles up for a 'new' and 'edit', therefore I change the 'action' attribute and the 'method' to reflect whether its a new record being created or an edit of an existing record.

Here is the form...

```
<div id="chardlg" class="easyui-dialog" title="Character" style="width:300px;padding:10px;" closed="true">
<form id="cf" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="cf">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input name="name" class="easyui-textbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Short Name:</td>
            <td><input name="short_name" class="easyui-textbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description:</td>
            <td><input name="description" class="easyui-textbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

You will note I have no 'method' or 'action'. I have tried it with these in place, same result.

Here is my javascript that manipulates the form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function newCharacter(){
    $('#chardlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','New Character');
    $('#cf').attr('action', charactersurl);
    $('#cf').attr('method', 'POST');
    $('#cf').form('clear');
}
function editCharacter(){
    var row = $('#cg').datagrid('getSelected');
    if (row){
        $('#chardlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','Edit Character');
        document.querySelector('#cf').action = basecharurl.concat(row.character_id);
        document.querySelector('#cf').setAttribute('method','PUT');
        //$('#cf').attr('action', basecharurl.concat(row.character_id));
        //$('#cf').attr('method', 'PUT');
        $('#cf').form('load', row);
    }
}
```

Through my browser debugger I can see the attributes changing as expected at each line, but when the URL is submitted, I can see on my FLASK console a 'GET' method instead of the correct 'PUT' or 'POST'. The rest of the URL is correct and if I test it with 'PUT' or 'POST' it works.

You will also note I have commented out the jquery way of setting the attributes, but that is only to demonstrate that I have tried both methods. Both methods set the correct attributes, but the query is still sent with a 'GET' method.

edit:
As requested here is the jquery datagrid that calls the functions...

```
$('#cg').datagrid({
    singleSelect:'true',
    url:charactersurl,
    method:'get',
    emptyMsg:'No Data available',
    toolbar:[{
        iconCls: 'icon-add',
        handler: function(){newCharacter()}
        },'-',{
        iconCls: 'icon-edit',
        handler: function(){editCharacter()}
        },'-',{
        iconCls: 'icon-remove',
        handler: function(){alert('Remove')}
    }],
    columns:[[
        {field:'name',title:'Name',width:100},
        {field:'short_name',title:'Short Name',width:100},
        {field:'description',title:'Description',width:120}
    ]]
});
```

Further messing about...
If I set the forms method in HTML ie...

```
<form id="cf" enctype="multipart/form-data" method='put' name="cf">
```

it still sends it as a 'get' request. The only place where 'get' is explicitly set is in the datagrid, but if I remove that the datagrid defaults to a 'POST' request and gets 400 from the FLASK backend and therefore will not populate the datagrid.

Seems like something is overwriting/overruling the 'method' attribute, as everything else is behaving as expected.

Comment: Where do you call `newCharacter()`?

Comment: Please share us how do you trigger those functions as well.

Comment: why you are using **document.querySelector** to get form

Comment: I have a jquery datagrid that lists all the characters. It retrieves those via REST, please see above edit.

Comment: I used document.querySelector as an alternative to the jquery method just to see if it was an issue with jquery. I get the same result whichever method I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, found that HTML forms only support GET and POST, PUT and DELETE are not supported. Very frustrating when its the recommended way to structure your REST requests. Phew, at least its not my code that was wrong.